# Decaying the learning rate from the 100th epoch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, epoch, learning-rate

Knowing that

```
learning_rate = 0.0004
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(
    model.parameters(),
    lr=learning_rate, betas=(0.5, 0.999)
)
```

is there a way of decaying the learning rate from the 100th epoch?

Is this a good practice:

```
decayRate = 0.96
my_lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ExponentialLR(optimizer=my_optimizer, gamma=decayRate)
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean by "*good solution*"; do you mean that the code will work, or that it is good ML practice? The first question is on-topic here, but the second is not - please notice the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: @desertnaut I changed my question

Comment: But now it seems like *two* questions, and largely irrelevant between them.

Answer (score 1):

```
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import MultiStepLR

# reduce the learning rate by 0.1 after epoch 100
scheduler = MultiStepLR(optimizer, milestones=[100,], gamma=0.1)
```

Please refer: [MultiStepLR](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR) for more information.